# how to filter values on a JSP's <form:select />?

Tags: forms, list, jsp, select, filter

I'd like to have JSP an auto filter for the values on a  element. Let's say I have loaded to the JSP a list of options like this:

- AAAA
- AAAB
- AABA
- AABB
- ABBA
- ABBB

What I want is a way to automatically filter the values whenever I type "AA" (which should display items: AAAA, AAAB, AABA and AABB) or "AB" (which should display only items: ABBA and ABBB).

I know it's quite easy on JSF, but is this feasible on JSP?

Thanks in advance,

gtludwig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a JavaScript problem, and doesn't have much to do with JSPs. You could use [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), or [Dojo](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/form/_autoComplete.html), or [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead), or [ExtJS](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/form/combos.html), or any other JavaScript framework that provides such a component.

Comment: We already use Twitter Bootstrap. I have successfully used the typeahead to filter down list items on an <input /> tag. but not on the <form: select />.

Comment: If you want a typeahead, and typeahead uses an input tag, why do you use a select tag?

Comment: I want users not to be able to select (or input) an item that's not on the list.

Comment: Couldn't you simply clear the input on blur if its value is not in the item list?

Comment: Didn't know I could do that. It might work! I'll check and see how it goes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could call server side (struts action, spring controller) to process your selection by Ajax, especially if the list is long.

`$.post("/yourAction", function(data) {`
`// here you can process data and change client side`
`});`

You can find more examples how to pass parameters and get result here:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: The lists is about 300+ items. We use Spring MVC (2.5) on this project, but so far we haven't been able to do just that. Can you throw me some link about it?